# Cannot import local git into Eclipse to create a new project (throws error "Connecting Git team provider failed")

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I created a git repository on my local computer:

```
git init
git add TestGit.java
git commit -m "Start"
```

I then went into Eclipse and chose to import and create a new project from that Git repo. During the Wizard steps, it recognized the `.git` directory and saw it as a repo (when I check in "Preferences", it shows under repositories) but when I then click to create the new project it fails everytime with:

```
Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
Error connecting project Git Test, no Git repositories found
```

What could be wrong?

**Edit:** If I import it as a general project instead of as a new Java project, then it works! Why?

Comment: related question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526179/egit-import-in-eclipse-showing-a-runtime-error

Answer (score 14):

In the *Import Projects from Git* dialog the *Use New project wizard* option seems to be broken (see [Eclipse bug 324145](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324145#c24)).

To import an existing Git repository use ***[File > Open Projects from File System...](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#import-projects)*** (instead of *File > Import... > Git > Projects from Git*). Because of the contained *TestGit.java* file the project is detected and configured as a Java project. The local Git repository is also detected and added automatically.

Only if it is a **Gradle** project (if it contains a `build.gradle` file), use ***File > Import...: Gradle > Existing Gradle Project*** instead ([at least until this feature request is implemented](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/356)).

Comment: Hard to believe the bug is still there as of today.

Comment: @lonelyloner I guess most people don't understand open source and write comments on Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: @howlger Do you mean I should fix the bug by myself, instead of posting comments on SO, because Eclipse is an open source application?

Comment: @lonelyloner No, that's not what I mean.

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me:
after selected *Use New project wizard* option, pay attention to select the workspace location, it should be set at the local repository location and not at the default workspace location.
I hope this help you!

Comment: This *does* seem to work, but the wizard is very brittle. The project name must be absolutely identical, and the path name must be absolutely identical. This wizard needs some work, and better error messages...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same error trying to clone and import. In the end I got it work using

```
File --> Import --> Git --> Projects from Git (with smart import)
```

which incidentally seems to clone the repository and then use the abovementioned

```
 File > Open Projects from File System...
```

Answer (score 0):

To me some of the above answers helped me. However, it wasn't perfect. Besides, my project was a Maven one on the Github. Here are my 9 steps.

1. (from github, copy https URL to clipboard)
2. (in STS-eclipse) File > Import
3. Git > Projects from Git > Next
4. Clone URI > Next
5. (paste copied URI into URI--it's automatic actually.) > Next > Next
6. (change "Directory:" box value if needed) > Next
7. (choose "Import as general project") > Next
   [image]
8. Finish
9. (right click project node) Configure > Convert to Maven Project
   [image]
10. Now the project should be a Maven project.
    [image]

End.