# EGit import in Eclipse showing a runtime error

Tags: eclipse, egit

I tried to make a really simple "hello world!" import using EGit in Eclipse. I have not found any evidence that the software is not working (no bug found in Google), so it looks I made something wrong which I do not know.

I followed the steps defined here: http://craigmart.in/2012/01/17/import-an-existing-git-repo-to-eclipse/

It crashes when connecting to GitHub.

Essentially this is what I am getting:

[image]

I have extracted the following information from the error log:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Connecting Git team provider failed. See log for details.
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ConnectProviderOperation.execute(ConnectProviderOperation.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.GitImportWizard$8.run(GitImportWizard.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2262)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.GitImportWizard.importProjects(GitImportWizard.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.GitImportWizard.access$2(GitImportWizard.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.GitImportWizard$4.run(GitImportWizard.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Contains: Error connecting project TEst2, no Git repositories found

eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
```

Info:

Using pycharm and GitHub directory I have been able to use Git and connect to GitHub... it looks a problem with something I did on Eclipse, not a problem with my computer.

Does anybody know what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Which steps led to this error?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann just added what I did, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Import Projects from Git* dialog the ***Use New project wizard*** option seems to be **broken** (see [Eclipse bug 324145](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324145#c24)).

**Workaround:**

Probably, the **problem occurred after the repository has been cloned** (otherwise you have to [clone the repository](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Cloning_or_adding_Repositories) first). To import an existing local Git repository use ***[File > Open Projects from File System...](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#import-projects)*** (instead of *File > Import... > Git > Projects from Git*). If the project is not an Eclipse project but contains *.java* files, the project will be configured automatically as a Java project. The local Git repository will also be detected and added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @howlger answer
I visualized the solution

[image]