# Importing project from a local git repository into the Eclipse Project Explorer not working

Tags: eclipse, git, tomcat, import

I cloned the following project from GitHub to the git view in eclipse:

https://github.com/nfrankel/twaattin

I want to have the project in my Project Explorer so I can work on it and run it (for testing purposes).

To this end, I went to the Project Explorer and did the following:

1. I clicked on "File"
2. I clicked on "Import"
3. I clicked on "Git" -> "Projects from Git"
4. I clicked on "Existing lock repository" -> "twaattin"
5. I chose "Import using the New Project wizard"
6. I clicked on "Finish"

Then the following window popped up:

[image]

7. I chose "Vaadin 8 Project"  and clicked "Next"

The following was displayed:

[image]

9. I chose the first option and clicked "Next"
10. On the next page I changed the Artifact id to "Twaattin" and clicked "Finish"

The structure of the project I wanted to import is the following:

[image]

But this was not imported to the Project Explorer. What I got instead was the following:

[image]

So I tried an alternative way ...

I repeated steps 1 to 4 from above but then in step 5 I chose "Import as general project".

After I clicked "Finish", the project became visible in the Project Explorer with its correct structure and I thought everything was fine.

However, now I got the following problem:

when I go to the Servers tab and right-click on my tomcat server and then choose "add and remove" from the menu, the imported project is not addable to the server so  can't run it !!

The only projects that I could add to the tomcat server are two old projects I did not import from git but created within the project explorer.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see the imported project (whose name is "Twaattin") is not amor the addable projects.

So my question is this:

How can I import a project from a local git repository into the Eclipse Project Explorer in a way that it can also be added to the tomcat server ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45537308/6505250

Comment: thank you  for your comment ... I did the workaround suggested in the approved answer to the question you link to ... the result is the same as with my second approach I tried and described above: the project is visible in the project explorer and everything seems fine ... however, the project is not addable to the tomcat server and can therefore not be run

Comment: Create a new empty project of the type you want and then copy missing <buildCommand>s and <nature>s of the `.project` file from the new to the target project.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand that ... I create a project of the type I want (in this case Vaaadin 8) ... and then I do what?

Comment: In the _Navigator_ view (which shows also files that are hidden in the _Project Explorer_) compare the `.project` files of the new project and of the project from Git. The `.project` file defines the available tooling.

Comment: ok, i copied the content (except, of course, then name tag) from the .project file of the new Vaadin 8 project to the .project file of the project from git ... I closed and restarted eclipse again but the project from git is still not addable to the tomcat server ... I think I'll give up and just use netbeans