# Importing Gradle project from existing Git Repository

Tags: eclipse, git, gradle

I am trying to import a Gradle project in Eclipse from Git. I am executing the following steps :

1. Clone an existing remote Repository ( Window - > Show -> Others - >Clone Existing Git repo and add to the view ). That step works perfectly fine. i have the whole Gradle project repo on my local drive.
2. File->Import->Projects from Git -> Existing Local Repository -> Select repo created in step1-> Import using new Project Wizard -> Gradle Project -> Select Project name and location
3. At this point Eclipse shows that it creates a Gradle project and tries to import it. Then I am getting a popup "Connecting Git Team Provider fails" and in the log "Error connecting , no repositories found." That's kind of strange since I clearly see local cloned repository in my system. It's also strange since when I am picking up an option to "Import General project" import works perfectly fine, but then I lose my Gradle structure.

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, 2019.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Import the Gradle project via _File > Import...: Gradle > Existing Gradle Project_. Git will be automatically detected.

Comment: It didn't recognize project as a Gradle projects. Event though I had all the code imported the structure of the project is not Gradle compliant and I don't see an imported project in the list of the Gradle tasks.

Comment: If you do _File > Import...: Gradle > Existing Gradle Project_, is the project folder icon decorated with the Gradle elephant or not?

Comment: It worked. Thank you, i made a mistake since I was always picking up from the Local Git rather than "Existing Gradle Project"

Answer (score 1):

Check if this is similar to Eclipse [bug 519140](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519140) and [324145](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=324145):

> I noticed that when I chose "`Import existing Project`" the problem doesn't happen

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45274093/6309) by [howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger):

> To import an existing Git repository use `File > Open Projects from File System...` (instead of `File > Import... > Git > Projects from Git`).

howlger adds though:

> `Open Projects from File System...` (alias [Smart Import](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Smart_Import)) recognizes many things (e.g. Java, Maven, etc.), but unfortunately *not* Gradle yet.

Comment: Yep, I tried it too and at the end it's the same thing. Eventually Eclipse asks you to define a project you want to import whether it's Gradle, General or something else and then it fails to import it correctly

Comment: Thanks for quoting me. But no rule without exception. _Open Projects from File System..._ (alias [_Smart Import_](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/Smart_Import)) recognizes many things (e.g. Java, Maven, etc.), but unfortunately not Gradle yet.

Comment: @VonC Thanks. I have extended the quoted answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Import the Gradle project via ***File > Import...: Gradle > Existing Gradle Project***.

Regardless of how you import or open a project, it will be automatically detected if the project is in a Git repository or not. The Git import dialog is only needed if you have not cloned the project yet.